# Play audio file in sequence

Tags: ios, audio, sequence

I work on iOS and I want to play many audio files, one after the other, without break, like it was an unique audio file.
When the audio player reads the first audio file, I don't have the next audio files, i need to update the queue, while playing.

Is it possible ? 
I insist on "without break"

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, have a look at [StreamingKit](https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit)

Comment: it doesn't work with .m4a audio file, any idea?

Comment: Currently StreamingKit requires files be optimised for streaming. http://forum.dbpoweramp.com/showthread.php?33946-Apple-Lossless-Encoder-quot-m4a-Layout-gt-Optimized-for-Streaming-quot-option